# Changing locale doesn't work for the date format in existing data model

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I was using Ukrainian locale in Windows system settings with English as default Office language.
This time I was working on the Excel Power Pivot intended for an English-speaking customer.
Having created the data model in the Excel workbook, I've discovered that it produced the Calendar table using Ukrainian names for months and week days. Well, it was according to how Windows system language was set. Then I changed Windows locate settings to English. No effect on the Calendar table. Deleted and re-created the Calendar table, still no effect. When I create a data model in a brand-new Excel file, it creates a Calendar table using current (English) locale. However, I'm unable to find a way to change it in the existing Excel workbook.

Is there any way to change locale in the existing data model?
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thank you.